# python3 sqlite inserting into specific table not working when hosting to vultr server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, server, hosting

I'm in the process of developing a discord bot which requires DB interactivity (via sqlite3) and everything works locally (when testing on PC).

But when it comes to putting the files on my vultr server and testing there, insert statements doesn't seem to work when it comes to one of the tables, and I can't seem to figure out what the fix for it is, because of how specific the issue appears to be.

I know that the issue isn't to do with my code given that it works locally (on my PC) and that the issue is only with inserting into one of the tables because insertion works on other tables.

Is there something that I'm not thinking of?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem had nothing to do with SQL or my code.

It was to do with the discord.py version that I was using requiring me to mention intents when it came to gathering member data.

Refer to the below for more information and on how I implemented the fix:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html